# JSpinner with dateModel "H:mm" updates hours instead of minutes when cursor in minutes zone

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

We have a `JSpinner` with `SpinnerDateModel` and `DateEditor`

```
    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel());
    spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "H.mm"));
```

[image]

If you click on hours and click on the arrows it will change hours, that's expected.

But, if you click in minutes zone after all digits, in this example, after '5' 
[image] and then click the arrows it will change hours instead of minutes.

steps:

1. click before '4' and click arrows. Hours will be changed
2. after this click in minutes zone after all digits (after '5') - still hours changed. But minutes should be changed, not hours

How to make minutes change if you click after all digits in minutes zone?

here is full source:

```
public class BoxFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BoxFrame frame = new BoxFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public BoxFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel());
        spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "H.mm"));
        contentPane.add(spinner);
    }
}
```

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau 2 lines of code above is the example. The spinner in the example has this problem

Comment: **Correction:** if you click after the minutes, it will update the *last thing that was updated*. E.g. click in-between the minute digits and the minutes will change. Click after them and the minutes will still change. Then click and change the hours and click after the minutes - now the hours change.

Comment: @Duncan > if you click after the minutes, it will update the last thing that was updated
that's true... But how to make it update minutes, but not "last thing that was updated"

Comment: I'd be surprised if there's an answer to this out there - it strikes me as one of those "that's the way it is" things. Perhaps you could create the behaviour you desire by having two spinners next to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the spinner asks the underlying `JFormattedTextField` what is selected when the cursor is on the right end, the calendar field index returned is `-1`, so the spinner get the next value based on the last selected field of the `Calendar`, which, in your case, is either `Calendar.HOUR` or `Calendar.MINUTE`. That value is set on the `SpinnerDateModel` when you click one of the arrows.

So to get what you want, you need to check if the index in the `JFormattedTextField` is the right most one and change it so it is within the `Calendar.MINUTE` field. Not pretty but it works.

```
 JSpinner.DateEditor editor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "H.mm") {

    @Override
    public JFormattedTextField getTextField() {
      JFormattedTextField txt = super.getTextField();
      int start = txt.getSelectionStart();
      int length = txt.getText().length();
      if (start == length) {
        txt.setSelectionStart(length - 1);
      }

      return txt;
    }
  };
```